# Qt and Bluetooth on Symbian S60

Tags: qt, bluetooth, symbian

i am working on a mobile application which needs to use bluetooth to send a file to another mobile device. I'm using Qt for symbian.
my problem is that Qt doesn't provide ready to use API for bluetooth.Only Qt extended(which runs on embedded linux) has API for bluetooth.
Do you have a clue to use bluetooth from Qt on symbian platform?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use native Symbian C++ for the Bluetooth part.

[Here's an article that shows how to mix Symbian C++ and Qt C++ with Bluetooth device discovery](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Using_Qt_and_Symbian_C%2B%2B_Together).